Building vector Noether current from twistor using Dirac formalism
There was a problem formulated during our lectures to build a Killing vector
$$
\nabla_{(\mu} k_{\nu)} = 0
$$
from equation
$$
{\nabla_{(C}}^{\dot{D}} \varkappa_{A)} = 0.
$$
For me it seems that
$$
k_\mu \leftrightarrow \varkappa^{A\dot{A}} = \varkappa^{A} \overline{\varkappa}^{\dot{A}}
$$
is an answer, since
$$
\nabla_\mu k_\nu = -\nabla_\nu k_\mu \leftrightarrow \nabla_{A\dot{A}} \varkappa_{B\dot{B}} = -\nabla_{B\dot{B}} \varkappa_{A\dot{A}}
$$
and after multiplying by $\varepsilon^{\dot{A}\dot{B}}$ we get
$$
\nabla_{A\dot{A}} \varkappa_B \overline{\varkappa}^{\dot{A}} = -\nabla_{B\dot{A}} \varkappa_A \overline{\varkappa}^{\dot{A}}.
$$
However, the proposed way was to construct
$$
\psi = (\varkappa^A,\varkappa_{\dot{B}})^T,
$$
and prove that
$$
k_\mu = \overline{\psi} \gamma_\mu \psi
$$
is a Killing vector, where
$$
\gamma^\mu =\begin{pmatrix}0&\overline{\sigma}^\mu\\\sigma^\mu&0\end{pmatrix},
$$
$$
\overline{\sigma}^\mu = \sigma^{\mu A\dot{B}},\quad \sigma^\mu = {\sigma^\mu}_{A\dot{B}}.
$$
I am not sure that this proposition was written correctly since indices do not make any sense for me. I also was not able to find anything close to this idea anywhere to at least check correctness of this ansatz.

And, given the nature of your question, can you be super-careful about formatting...? Thanks...

What is the problem with formatting?..

Maybe nothing! :) I was just wanting to be sure that you write what you intended. :)
